# JavaScript - 'this' within overridden canvas onmousedown

Tags: javascript, canvas, prototype

I have the following code snippet:

```
VIEW.CTX = function(canvas){
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.canvas.onmousedown = this.onDocumentMouseDown;

    //more stuff...
};

VIEW.CTX.prototype = {
    constructor: VIEW.CTX
};
```

and later

```
VIEW.CTX.prototype.onDocumentMouseDown = function(event){
    console.log(this);
    this.doSomething();
}
```

When I create an instance of CTX and call onDocumentMouseDown directly:

```
var ctx = new VIEW.CTX(theCanvas);
ctx.onDocumentMouseDown('');
```

'this' refers to my instance of CTX. However, when I invoke onDocumentMouseDown by clicking on the canvas, 'this' refers to the canvas element, and I get an error when it tries to call `this.doSomething();`. How do I make it refer to its instance of CTX instead of the canvas element?

Comment: The solution is `this.canvas.onmousedown = this.onDocumentMouseDown.bind(this)` or store the constructor `this` in a variable (`var that=this;`) and do `...onmousedown = function(e) { that.onDocumentMouseDown(e); }` I'll see if I can find the most appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @aspillers Your .bind() solution worked for me. You should post it as an answer.